# Css - White Space that i cant resolve

Tags: html, css, whitespace

Ive looked all over the web including scouring the entirety of stack overflow but everything ive tried simply does not work.

My html and css code is as follows. the problem is a large white space occupying the bottom of the page.

```css
body
{
  background-image: url("img/background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.box
{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 80%;
  top: 20%;
  background-image: url("img/box.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80%;
  height: 100%;
}
.box img{
  display: block;
}
.explore
{
  vertical-align: top;
  position: absolute;
  right: 42%;
  width: 10%;
  top: 70%;
  background-image: url("img/explore.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80%;
  height: 100%;
}
.explore img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Harry Roper Design</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class = "box"></div>
    <div class = "explore"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `height: 100%;` from your CSS to resolve the "large white space occupying the bottom of the page" problem.

And there is no accepptable reason to use two `div` as `body` content with `absolute` positioning in CSS

Comment: When i remove the height parts though it then doesnt display the content?

Comment: please explain to me why are u using position: absolute”?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's no white space.

I've used dummy images to emulate your website and added borders to div elements so you will be able to see what's going on:

http://jsfiddle.net/9xcwjxb6/

Firstly - setting `top: 70%;` and `height: 100%;` moves your `.explore` div 70% down the page AND sets its height at 100%, it means you're ending up with the total height of 170% and thats where comes your "white space" from (which is, in fact, not white space, but your `.explore` element).

I think you should read more about [centering in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) because I guess that's what you've tried to achieve here.

The proper solution should look closer to this:

```
body {
  background: url("http://dummyimage.com/2000x2000/999999/fff&text=+") no-repeat;
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -225px;
    margin-left: -300px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 600px;
}

.box {
  background: url("http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff") no-repeat;
  height: 400px;
}

.explore {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  background: url("http://dummyimage.com/200x50/000/fff") no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

[See it live](http://jsfiddle.net/jc8g4s86/)

Or you could use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if you don't care about support for older browsers.